# generic data type id

Tags: java, objective-c

in Objective-C we have the generic data type called id. We can create a mutable array of type id and I can then add into the array objects from different classes as below:

```
 Bannana *banana = [[Banana alloc] init];
 Apple *apple = [[Apple allloc] init];

 NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [myArray addObject:banana];
 [myArray addObject:apple];
```

Question: What is the equivalent of "id" in Java? How can I accomplish the above in Java? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Fruit` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) and have `Banana` and `Apple` classes implement that.

After that you can do the following:

```
Fruit banana = new Banana();
Fruit apple = new Apple();

List<Fruit> myList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
myList.add(banana);
myList.add(apple);
```

You can also use the [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class for the type of the list, but then you need to be careful when you get objects out of the list as they are going to be of type `Object` and casting will be required based on the type of each object:

```
List<Object> myArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
myArray.add(car);
myArray.add(banana);

for (Object o : myArray) {
    if (o instanceof Car) {
        Car c = (Car) o;
        System.out.println("Car object found.");
        // use Car object
    } else if (o instanceof Banana) {
        Banana b = (Banana) o;
        System.out.println("Banana object found.");
        // use Banana object
    } else {
        System.err.println("Unknown object found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I gave a bad example for the classes but suppose they were completely different such as Banana class and Car class, both would have completely different implementations and the interface would not be the best approach...

Comment: @Pupillam: I've added some extra code that demonstrate the use of a list of Objects (any type as long as it's an object, not primitive). Note the use of `instanceof` operator to determine the type of each object upon retrieval from the list.

Comment: You can add primitives to the list as well, in which case they will be [autoboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to their corresponding object wrapper classes. So `int` value becomes `Integer` object upon storing it in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is kind of similar to `Object` in java. Everything thing in Java (except the primitive types) is object. 
If you just want to use a mutable list to store any types, you can do this but not recommand:

```
List myArray = new ArrayList();
myArray.add(banana);
myArray.add(apple);
```